# Can't add parenthesis in the second parameter of addEventListener method

Tags: javascript

This confused me a lot

```
var show = function(){
    console.log('wow');
};

var show2 = function(word){
    console.log(word);
};

button_element.addEventListener('click', show2('wow'), false)
```

'wow' //it return the string immediately but hit the button, nothing output in the console,

but

```
button_element.addEventListener('click', show. false)
```

No string return as we expect and then hit the button `wow` shows in the console as intended

anybody explain why does it act this way?

Comment: Post the actual code, what you've shown here [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/uycyJ/)

Comment: @Incognito What the asker wrote appears to be the actual code. Your example code doesn't work fine. To work as expected, the log should be written to the console when the element is clicked.

Comment: @DanHerbert Woops, still havne't had my coffee. I was looking at it after onload and reading the text "works fine." Headed to the coffee shop now...

Comment: @Incognito Thanks for clean up my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`addEventListener` takes a *function* as its second argument. Once you call a function, it means you're passing the *returned value* of that function, not the function itself. If you want to use a function call in `addEventListener` like you're trying to do, you should add a nested function that gets returned when you call it.

Try this:

```
var show2 = function(word){ 
                return function(){ console.log(word); }
            };
button_element.addEventListener('click', show2('wow'), false);
```

In the example above, the call to `addEventListener` is sent the inner function, which will have the captured value of the `word` variable within it.

Comment: just your second sentence is enough for me to clear all confusion out. Thanks